# Using ImageStyle with dependency injection

Tags: 8

Is there a way to use the *ImageStyle* class with dependency injection instead of a static call?

I am struggling to find an example.

At the moment I have a block which is importing the class with

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

And then calls the *load* method with

```
ImageStyle::load('machine_name')->buildUrl($path);
```

But I am wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, inject the [`entity_type.manager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_type.manager/8.7.x) service and load it that way:

```
$url = $this->entityTypeManager
  ->getStorage('image_style')
  ->load('machine_name')
  ->buildUrl($path);
```

Comment: I must learn to type a bit faster ;)

Comment: +1 to you, I think I'll delete my answer as I posted right after you :)

Comment: It worked, thank you!